# Querying the cache in rails still runs a call against the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, activerecord

I'm probably missing something very simple here, but can't understand what.

I'm trying to cache a simple active record query but every time I touch the cache, it runs the query against the DB again.

Controller Code:

```rb
products = Rails.cache.read("search_results")
if products
    render :text => products[0].id
else
    products = Product.where('name LIKE ?", 'product_name?')
    Rails.cache.write("search_results", products)
end
```

I can see that in my second call I get to the if block and not the else, but any time I'm trying to touch products (like rendering it) I also see an active record call to the DB.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not an answer, but consider using [`fetch`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch) instead of doing the read and write yourself.

Answer (score 7):

The line

```
products = Product.where('name LIKE ?", 'product_name?')
```

returns an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html), but does *not* hit the database unless a kicker method is called on it.

While I would still recommend using `fetch` as mentioned in my comment above, try changing the line to:

```
products = Product.where('name LIKE ?", 'product_name?').all
```

which will force the database hit, and save the actual results of the query into the cache, instead of the relation.

Comment: thank you so much. This really helped after going through a lot of blogs.